# Javascript: Parse a string and find same named items in string and total them

Tags: javascript

I have a comma-separated string (it will vary and not always include the same data) that I need to find all the items that are the same and then tally the numbers that are present. The string will always look something like this as it is being pulled from a feed:

Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (6.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (6.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours)

I need to list each class type, like Algebra or Athletic (Attendance), with the total number of credits possible. So, for this example, I would ultimately need to end up with a variable that I can display that reads, "Algebra (26.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (26.50 hours). In this particular example, the hours for both classes are the same but that will not always be the case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Any code you could show us?

Comment: regex is your friend. btw if you have control over the feed, change the feed to give you readable data instead of a weird string.

Comment: Write some code to do it, then come back to us for assistance when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (6.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (6.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours)'
str.split(',').map(function(s){
  return {
    hours: s.match(/\((\d\.\d)+.+\)$/)[1].trim(),
    title: s.match(/^(.+)\(/)[1].trim()
  };
}).reduce(function(prev, current){
  if (!prev[current.title]) {
    prev[current.title] = 0;
  }
  prev[current.title] += parseFloat(current.hours);
  return prev;
}, {})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35t1h7oe/)

Comment: Nice. Much more concise than my old school way.

Comment: Would you mind setting this up in jsfiddle? This is returning [object Object] when I assign to a variable.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

First, split your string. 
    var split=string.split(',');

The create an array. 
    var array = [] ;

Then loop through the split to get all values

```
for (var i=0;i<split.length;i++){
   array.push(split[i][0]);
  }
```

The  use a unique array function (you need to add this,  see below

```
var uniqueArray=array.unique();
```

next loop through the unique array to push total values (requires a loop within a loop)

```
  var totals =[];
  for(var u=0;u<uniqueArray.length;u++){
    var totalThis=0;
    for(var i=0;i<split.length;i++){
     if(uniqueArray[u]!=split[i][0]){continue;} 
     totalThis+=1;
    }
   totals.push([uniqueArray[u], totalThis]) 
}
```

put this code outside your function

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(!arr.contains(this[i])) {
            arr.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var s = "Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (6.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (6.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours)"
var splitResults = s.split(',');
var results = {};

for (var i = 0; i < splitResults.length; i++) {
    // Get the item name by looking for anything before the ( and stripping the extra space
    var item = splitResults[i].replace(/(.*?)\(.*/i, "$1").replace(/\s/g, '');

    // Get the item hours by finding the digit, including decimal point inside parenthesis
    var hours = splitResults[i].replace(/.*\(([0-9\.]+)\shours\)/i, "$1");

    // The iteem doesn't already exists in the struc
    if (results[item] === undefined) {
        results[item] = parseFloat(hours);
    }
    else {
        // Add the hours to the existing item
        results[item] += parseFloat(hours);
    }
}

// Outputs: Object {Algebra: 26.5, Athletic: 26.5}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this

```
var str = "Algebra (6.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours)";

var arr = str.split(",");
arr = arr.map(function(item,i,self){
    var object = item.trim();
  return {
    subj: object.split(" ")[0],
    time: object.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ")[1].split("").reverse().join("").split("(")[1]
  }
});



console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one approach, adding each class and hours total to a unordered list.

See JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/khristopherallen/8p868nwf/

```
var feedData="Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (4.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (3.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (6.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Algebra (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (5.50 hours), Science (2.25 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (6.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), Reading (2.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours), History (2.50 hours), History (6.50 hours), Athletic (Attendance) (2.50 hours)";

function parseFeedData(data){
    var returnValue = "";
    var classes = new Object();
    var splitItems = data.split(', ');

    $(splitItems).each(function(index,value){
         var className = value.substring(0,value.lastIndexOf('(')).trim();
         var classHours = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('('),value.length).trim().split(' ')[0].substring(1);

        if (classes[className] == null){
            classes[className] = new Object();
            classes[className].name = className;
        }

        if (classes[className].hours == null){
            classes[className].hours = 0;
        }

        if (parseFloat(classHours) != NaN){
            classes[className].hours += parseFloat(classHours);
        }
    });
    for (var i in classes){
        $('#classes').append("<li>" + classes[i].name  + ": " + classes[i].hours + " hours</li>")
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    parseFeedData(feedData);
});
```